# How can I get org mode to cooperate with htmlize?

Tags: org-mode

I've been maintaining my personal webpage by using the `htmlize` feature with `org-mode`. Basically, I have a directory `~/webpage` with many subdirectories containing `.org` files. I then run a script that finds each `.org` file under `~/webpage` and runs `htmlize` on the file. The script is:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/home/brian/.emacs.d/elpa/htmlize-20130207.1202/")
(require 'htmlize)

(defun htmlize-files-in-dir (dir)
  (htmlize-many-files (directory-files dir t ".org$")))
```

My issue is that in order for each page to conform to my emacs theme, the script has to open a new instance of emacs for each file. After some googling I found that there exists a function `org-export-htmlize-generate-css` that would generate a global css style file for my theme. Obtaining such a css file would allow my script to run a lot faster (and would prevent the annoying emacs windows from flashing every time I run the script). However, my version of emacs (24.3.1) does not have the function `org-export-htmlize-generate-css`. Does anyone have an idea how I could obtain this function?

Comment: Install the `org-ehtml` package. I have the `org-export-htmlize-generate-css` command, and I think it comes from that package. However, I do not know whether this will solve your problem and answer the question in the title. If it does solve your problem, I can post it as an answer to be more visible for future readers, but others might have better advice for your issue.

Comment: I just installed `org-ehtml` and I still don't have `org-export-htmlize-generate-css`

Comment: Sorry, as you have realized, I was mistaken. It looks like this function is in a file called `ox-html.el` which I think is actually bundled with my version of `org-mode`. I am using the "stock" version of `org-mode` that comes with emacs, but I am on emacs 24.5, so I am sure that is why I have it and you don't. You could potentially install a newer version of `org-mode` by following these instructions: http://orgmode.org/manual/Installation.html#Installation and that might get you the function you are looking for, but I wouldn't swear to it.

Comment: I'm running org version 8.3.2. Which do you have?

Comment: Ha, OK, I am running `8.2.10`, so I guess getting a newer version might not do the trick...If it helps at all, I found the `ox-html.el` file in `/usr/local/share/emacs/24.5(3 in your case)/lisp/org`

Comment: Hmm... My `/usr/local/share/emacs/24.3/` contains only a `site-lisp` directory, and it is empty.

Comment: Actually, I have a `~/elisp/org-mode/lisp/ox-org.el` file.

Comment: This might explain why you don't have the files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777426/emacs-org-mode-export-ox-html-ox-latex-cannot-open-load-file My version of emacs was built from source. If you are interested, you can follow these easy instructions to do the same (just replace the version number): http://askubuntu.com/questions/437255/how-to-install-emacs-24-4-on-ubuntu It seemed like a scary process for me before I tried it, but now I also install emacs this way

Comment: What distro are you running?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33064/discussion-between-elethan-and-brian-fitzpatrick).